# Approximating $L^p$ functions by eigenfunctions of Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading a paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039608004932.

In this paper,  the authors assume that $\mathcal{O}$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $C^m$ boundary and  $p\geq 2$.
Let's consider the eigen-system of the Dirichlet Laplacian $\Delta$ on $\mathcal{O}$, there exists numbers $0>\lambda_1>\lambda_2\geq\lambda_3\geq\cdots$ and functions $\{\omega_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that
$\{\omega_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is an orthogonal basis of $H_0^1(\mathcal{O})$ and an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathcal{O})$ and $\omega_k$ is the eigenfunction of $\Delta$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. Then we can define the finite-dimensional projection $P_m$ on $L^2(\mathcal{O})$ by
$$P_mv \dot{=}\sum_{k=1}^{m}(v,\omega_k)_{L^2}\omega_k\in L^2.$$
In the statement of Theorem 4.4 in this paper, the authors assume that $\partial \mathcal{O}$ is $C^m$ with $m\geq 2$ integer such that
$$m\geq \frac{N(p-2)}{2p}.$$
It is claimed in (4.10) of this paper that under this assumption, we have for $v\in L^p(\mathcal{O})\cap H_0^1(\mathcal{O})$
$$ P_mv\rightarrow v \text{ in $L^p(\mathcal{O})\cap H_0^1(\mathcal{O})$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$}. $$
I wonder whether the convergence in $L^p(\mathcal{O})$ is true?

---

I think the following may be related to the answer. It has been claimed at the begining of section 5 in https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-29/issue-4/Stochastic-two-dimensional-euler-equations/10.1214/aop/1015345773.full that there exist a set of Schauder basis $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty\subseteq L^2(\mathcal{O})$, an orthogonal projection $Q_m:L^2(\mathcal{O})\rightarrow span\{e_1,...,e_m\}$ and constant $C>0$ independent of $m$ such that
$$\|Q_mv\|_{L^p(\mathcal{O})}\leq C\|v\|_{L^p(\mathcal{O})}.$$

I also wonder whether the family $\{\omega_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of eigenfunctions of Dirichlet Laplacian is a Schauder basis in ${L^p(\mathcal{O})}$.

Comment: Something in the paper is not clear to me, too. It is true that $P_m v \to v$ in $H^1$ and then in $L^p$ if $2\leq p \leq 2*$ (assuming $v \in H_0^1$). The same holds in $H^{2m}$ (plus some b.c.) using elliptic regularity and here the regularity of the boundary enters) but assuming at least $v \in H^{2m}$ and then in $L^p$ for those $p$ for which the Sobolev embedding holds. But I doubt more. Concerning the general question, this is not true. Spherical harmonics in several dimensions are a basis in $L^p $ only for $p=2$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you for your answer, it helps me a lot. I think the question I asked is not true in general.  The eigenfunctions of Dirichlet Laplacian cannot be a Schauder basis in $L^p(\mathcal{O})$. Once it is a Schauder basis, by approximating by functions in $H^{2m}$, the limit can be shown... I'm also interested in the boundary condition you just mentioned. Is there any reference showing how the boundary condition is used in showing the limit?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune  May I ask one more question? at the begining of section 5 in https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-29/issue-4/Stochastic-two-dimensional-euler-equations/10.121p4/aop/1015345773.full, the authors said that they can take a family $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq W^{2,2}(\mathcal{O})\cap W^{2,p}(\mathcal{O})$ which is an orthonormal basis in $H^1_0(\mathcal{O})$ and a Schauder basis in $W^{1,p}(\mathcal{O})$, how can I achieve this? (Here, the domain  $\mathcal{O}$ is unbounded with smooth boundary)

Comment: Concerning the b.c I have in mind the following. You may consider powers of the laplacian $(-\Delta)^m$ as a new self-adjoint operator to repeat the argument. I mean: if $u \in D(-\Delta)^m$ (D stands for domain) then the series $\sum_n (u,u_n)u_n$ converges to $u$ in the graph norm. By elliptic regularity this graph norm is that of $H^{2m}$ but only on the domain which is smaller. If $m=1$ the domain is $H^2 \cap H^1_0$. If $m=2$ you get $u \in H^2 \cap H^1_0$ such that $\Delta u \in H^2 \cap H^1_0$ (so $\Delta u=0$ at the boudary)...and so on

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune  It's a good interpretation... I think it is how the b.c is introduced.. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: For the other question, I don't know. If I undestand they need a special basis, unrelated to eigenfunctions. Some smoothed version of the Haar system? @Bill Johnson should know it. What prevents eigenfunctions to be a Schuader basis is the growth of $L^p$ norm for $p \neq 2$, unless the domain has some special structure, as a rectangle.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune  I think what they need is unrelated to the eigenfunctions. A smooth version of Haar system sounds like a good angle. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I think the first question is finally addressed. I believe that the authors has lost the condition $v_\tau\in H^m$. Thanks a lot for your interpretation in how the b.c is introduced.